# Adding a Span tag to a CI form label tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

With how my template is set up I'm attempting to put a span tag inside of a form label for my Codeigniter login form.

I know I'm doing this wrong but not sure on my fix and hoping someone could clue me in. When I have this rendered it gives me an array to string conversion error.

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'span12', 'id' => 'username');
echo form_input('<span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-user-3 right gray marginR10"></span>username', '', $attributes);
```

Comment: You'll have to use a label for that, it won't work with form_input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple like:

```
echo "<label for='short'>**<span class='icon16 icomoon-icon-user-3'></span>**Short Description</label><br/>";
$attributes = array('name'=>'shortdesc','class' => 'span12','id'=>'username');
echo form_input($attributes);
```

Comment: Not saying I'm not going to use it but just so I know for future uses there's no way of adding in html into those form functions.

Comment: @KevinSmith it's good to have curiosity,AFAIK using CI form function is not possible to do this but using normal html you can do that!